# Firebase android. What if I add the same listener multiple times?

Tags: java, android, firebase

If I add the same listener object

```
private ValueEventListener dataChangedListener = new ValueEventListener() ...

        mQery.addValueEventListener(dataChangedListener);
        mQery.addValueEventListener(dataChangedListener);
```

It would be the same as if I added it once? And if I want to remove it I should just call

```
        mQery.removeEventListener(dataChangedListener);
```

Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether ***removeEventListener*** will work or not yourself, by simply updating some data in the database and observing whether your ***onDataChanged*** gets called or not.

Concerning whether it would be the same as adding it once: I had the same question, so I checked the Firebase [sources](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/tree/03bc30bc99fbd66068d6c3c3661cd972b6e16de1/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/database). As far as I understand **(I'm no expert in this by any means)**, Firebase does add a new object in the Listener list but it points to the same listener added earlier.

You can take a look at the [sources](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/tree/03bc30bc99fbd66068d6c3c3661cd972b6e16de1/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/database) yourself for a detailed examination.

Edit: To clarify, I'll add some screenshots...

This is what happens if I register the same child listener twice. The onChildAdded gets called twice and populates the list with Milk 2x.

[image: This is what happens if I register the same child listener twice]

Comment: Thanks for answer. So when firebase goes through the list of listeners it will call the same object's onDataChanged multiple times anyway

Comment: If this answers your question, consider selecting a best answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't be the same. If you have multiple references all pointing to the exact same location in your Firebase database, and you have listeners on all those references, then any change to the data at that location will trigger all of the listeners.

If you don't want a listener to trigger on a change, remove it from the reference where you have added it in the first place. As far as I know, there is no way to conditionally indicate that a listener should be triggered based on some other condition - you just add and remove them.